# challenge with nested divs in a table across browser versions

Tags: html

I'm having no end of problems with this layout. When I make a change a change to fix elements in relation to one another in one browser version, all the other versions go out of whack. 
I have been dealing with this issue for months now, far too long.

The code below represents three nested divs. The one on the inside gets XML data imported into it in a nav tree. No matter what I do, the UI gets thrown off all over the page. Any ideas for solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

Update: not sure why, but the included code gets cut off in the middle. If anyone looking has trouble seeing the code, please let me know. Thanks!

```
 <tbody style="display:block; height:100%; max-height:754px !important">
    <tr id="tdHeightAdjust" valign="top" style="background-color:#f0f0f0;      height:22px;">
     <!--   <span style="height:22px; background-color:#f0f0f0;">-->
        <td style="width:30%;" rowspan="3">
                                                                                                  <div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;background-color:white">     
                 <!--;border-right:solid 1px #999999;-->
       <div id="TreePaneDiv" style="width:100%;height:100%;border-left:1px solid #999999;border-top:1px solid #999999;background-color:White;"> 
<div onselectstart="stopSelectStart();" class="Tree-container"   id="TREEAPPTARGETDIV"     style="background-color:white;padding:6px;height:750px;max-height:100%;max-width:100%">
       </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: I think you're missing code.  I see an opening tr tag, but never an opening td tag.  Can you edit your question?

Comment: @Matthew, yes not sure, what's going on with this. I'll take another crack now at including it all. Okay, should be better now. :)

Comment: The real question here is, width 100% CSS setting is supposed to default to %100 of the next enclosing container element. In previous versions of IE, this works. In IE10 It defaults to 100% of the entire document. Why?

Comment: I don't understand why on Stack Overflow it asks me to indent all code by 4 spaces, fine, but when I try to indent, a lot of the lines don't allow it, and my code gets cut off in the middle into separate containers, or it's not readable at all.

Comment: That's how it knows what is code.  How is the UI getting "thrown off all over the page"?  I can't tell from the snippet what is causing the issue, but it might help to separate out the styles from the HTML.  Inline styles make the code harder to read and maintain.  Is there a live version of this somewhere?

Comment: Okay, I get it with the coding indenting. No problem. Hey Matthew, there is a live version, but I cannot grant access because it's a pay site. I found a solution to this problem. It's not perfect, but  I just branched to set the CSS differently depending on the version of IE.

Comment: IE is the cause of so many issues.  I actually just spent an hour on my site getting IE 7 to match up with how it looks in every other browser.  Glad you got it working though!